# Nested where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to structure a WHERE statement to act like this pseudocode? Kind of like a nested WHERE statement?

```
SELECT
   t.Val1
   ,t.Val2
   ,t.Val3
   ,t.Val4
   ,t.Val5
FROM table t
WHERE
   IF t.Val1 = 'ABC' 
      THEN WHERE t.Val2 = t.Val3
   ELSE
      WHERE t.Val4 = t.Val5
```

Using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use boolean logic:

```
WHERE (t.Val1 = 'ABC' AND t.Val2 = t.Val3) OR
      (t.Val1 <> 'ABC' AND t.Val4 = t.Val5)
```

This formulation assumes that `val1` is never `NULL` -- `NULL` values are easily handled, if necessary.

Comment: Only thing I would recommend is wrapping the OR in parentheses as well, in case OP has other where conditions and doesn't understand logical order of operations. The AND parentheses are unnecessary but visually helpful, if there are any other where conditions the OR parentheses would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A third alternative to the other solutions would be IIF expressions.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test;

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    TestID TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
    ,Val1 VARCHAR(3)
    ,Val2 INT
    ,Val3 INT
    ,Val4 INT
    ,Val5 INT
)
;
GO

INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES
(1, 'ABC', 1, 1, 1, 2)
,(2, 'ABC', 1, 2, 2, 2)
,(3, 'XYZ', 1, 1, 1, 2)
,(4, 'XYZ', 1, 2, 2, 2)
;

SELECT
    *
FROM #Test
WHERE IIF(Val1 = 'ABC', Val2, Val4) = IIF(Val1 = 'ABC', Val3, Val5)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use case statement instead of where condition.
even you can to make computed column by case statement like the below link :

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/27/sql-server-computed-column-conditions-case-statement/